# Подскажите что значит &=

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такая строка кода

```
correctAnswer &= ((answer.correct && answerCheckbox.checked) || (!answer.correct && !answerCheckbox.checked));
```

Никак не могу понять, что значит `&=`, как это работает?
Как вы уже поняли код не мой.

Comment: [побитовое И](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это оператор присваивания с побитовым AND. Обозначает он следующее:

```
correctAnswer = correctAnswer & ((answer.correct && answerCheckbox.checked) || correctAnswer & (!answer.correct && !answerCheckbox.checked));
```

Подробнее можно прочитать здесь: [https://developer.mozilla.org...](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)